# How to adjust size/color of svg image in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, next.js

I want to adjust the color and size of an svg image "headset.svg".

Before I was using next/image:

```
<Image
  src={'/headset.svg'}
  alt='logo'
  width={30}
  height={30}
  className='object-contain'
/>
```

This works well for the size but I want to change the color (in css) as well.

I've added the svgr tool to make a component of the svg image.

next.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    webpack(config) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      })
      return config
    },
  }
```

Code:

```
import Logo from '../public/headset.svg';
...
<Logo className='w-[50px] h-[50px] text-black' />
```

But the css (className='w-[50px] h-[50px] text-black') is not being applied to the svg image.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the properties of the svg after it has been loaded in an `<img />` tag

One of the ways to customize an svg is the following.

Copy the contents of your svg file (it is actually a tag that you can use)

Create a Custom Component that returns the svg code

```
const MyCustomSvg = (props) => {
    return <svg>...<svg/>
}
```

You can then pass classes or styles to this component and change it's color or width (be aware that svg-s use fill for the background-color and stroke for the border):

```
// the svg component
const MyCustomSvg = ({className,style}) => {
  return (
     <svg className={className} style={style}>
         ...
     <svg/>
  )
}

function RandomComponent() {
  
  return (
   <div>
     <MyCustomSvg 
         className={"fill-red-600 stroke-black"} 
         style={{width:20,height:20}} 
     />
   </div>
  )
}
```

That way you are going to render a real svg tag, not an image tag, pretending to be a svg.

If you wish to recolor different paths of the svg, you can pass specific styles for just the path tags.:

```
const MyCustomSvg = ({className,style,style1,style2}) => {
  return <svg className={className} style={style}>
          <path style={style1} d="..." />
          <path style={style1} d="..." />
         <svg/>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Added "filter brightness-0" to the Image className and reverse the opacity for hover. Removed the svgr plugin.

```
          <Link href='/' className='z-30 opacity-100 hover:opacity-50'>
            <Image
              src='/headset.svg'
              alt='logo'
              width={30}
              height={30}
              className='object-contain filter brightness-0'
            />
          </Link>
```